# having a problem with my java BST search implementation

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

I'm having problems with my bst search implementation method but I don't know why I keep getting an error once it gets to Alice? Not sure if its because it can't find it or if I implemented my insert incorrectly? Any help will be much appreciated.

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * This is an implementation of a Binary Search Tree (BST).
 *
 */
public class BinarySearchTree {

    /**
     * Class containing key (name) for a node and right and left children
     */
    class Node {

        private String key;

        public String getKey() {
            return key;
        }

        public void setKey(String key) {
            this.key = key;
        }


        private Node left;

        public Node getLeft() {
            return left;
        }

        public void setLeft(Node left) {
            this.left = left;
        }


        private Node right;

        public Node getRight() {
            return right;
        }

        public void setRight(Node right) {
            this.right = right;
        }

        Node(String key) {
            this.key = key;
            right = null;
            left = null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * The root of the binary search tree (BST)
     */
    Node root;

    // Constructor 
    BinarySearchTree() {  
        root = null;  
    } 

    // Search for a given key in BST
    public Node search(String key) 
    { 
        Node node = null;
        node = searchRecursive(root, key);
        return node;
    }

    // Implement the search recursively in this helper function
    Node searchRecursive(Node root_node, String key) 
    { 
        //Node someNode = new Node(key);

            /**
             * TODO
             * 
             */
            Node someNode = new Node(key);
            if(root_node != null) {
                int comparison = someNode.getKey().compareTo(root_node.getKey());

                if(comparison < 0) {
                    root_node.left = insertRecursive(root_node.left, key);
                }else if(comparison > 0) {
                    root_node.right = insertRecursive(root_node.right, key);
                }
            }else{
                root_node = new Node(key);
            }
            return root_node;





    }

    // Insert a new Node with a key and value in BST
    public void insert(String key) {
        root = insertRecursive(root, key); 
    }

    // Implement the insert recursively in this helper function
    Node insertRecursive(Node root_node, String key) { 
        /**
         * TODO
         * 
         */
        Node someNode = new Node(key);
        if(root_node != null) {
        int comparison = someNode.getKey().compareTo(root_node.getKey());



        if(root_node == null) {
            root_node = new Node(key);
            return root_node;
        }

        if(comparison < 0) {
            root_node.left = insertRecursive(root_node.getLeft(), key);
        }else if(comparison > 0) {
            root_node.right = insertRecursive(root_node.getLeft(), key);
        }

        }
        return root_node;



    } 


    // A recursive inorder traversal of the BST 
    void inorder(Node root, ArrayList<String> strList) { 
        if (root != null) { 
            inorder(root.getLeft(), strList); 
            System.out.println(root.getKey()); 
            strList.add(root.getKey());
            inorder(root.getRight(), strList); 
        }
    }



    public static void main(String[] args) { 

        //For runtime computations
        long startTime, endTime;
        double duration = 0;


        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        BinarySearchTree bst = new BinarySearchTree(); 
        /**
         * TODO:
         * Read in the names from the names.txt file, and
         * Insert all the names in the BST by calling:
         *  insert(name)
         */
        bst.insert("alice");
        bst.insert("zoe");
        bst.insert("alex");

        endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        duration += ((double) (endTime - startTime));
        System.out.println("BST insertion runtime is " + duration);

        /**
         * So an inorder traversal of the tree, ensure the result is 
         * order lexicographically
         */
        ArrayList<String> strList = new ArrayList<String>();
        bst.inorder(bst.root, strList);
        //Ensure the inorder traversal gives a 
        //lexicographic ordering of the names
        for (int i = 1; i < strList.size(); i++) {
            assertTrue(strList.get(i-1).compareTo(strList.get(i)) <= 0  );
        }

        /**
         * Verify that search returns the correct result
         */
        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Node n = bst.search("aaaa");
        assertEquals(n, null);
        endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        duration = ((double) (endTime - startTime));
        System.out.println("BST search runtime for aaaa is " + duration);


        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        n = bst.search("alice");
        assertEquals(n.getKey(), "alice");
        endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        duration = ((double) (endTime - startTime));
        System.out.println("BST search runtime for alice is " + duration);


        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        n = bst.search("zoe");
        assertEquals(n.getKey(), "zoe");
        endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        duration = ((double) (endTime - startTime));
        System.out.println("BST search runtime for zoe is " + duration);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have incorrect placement of braces in `insertRecursive` implementation when root is null.

Change

```
Node insertRecursive(Node root_node, String key) { 
    /**
     * TODO
     * 
     */
    Node someNode = new Node(key);
    if(root_node != null) {
    int comparison = someNode.getKey().compareTo(root_node.getKey());



    if(root_node == null) {
        root_node = new Node(key);
        return root_node;
    }

    if(comparison < 0) {
        root_node.left = insertRecursive(root_node.left, key);
    }else if(comparison > 0) {
        root_node.right = insertRecursive(root_node.right, key);
    }

    }
    return root_node;
}
```

to

```
Node insertRecursive(Node root_node, String key) { 
    /**
     * TODO
     * 
     */
    Node someNode = new Node(key);
    if(root_node != null) {
        int comparison = someNode.getKey().compareTo(root_node.getKey());

        if(comparison < 0) {
            root_node.left = insertRecursive(root_node.left, key);
        }else if(comparison > 0) {
            root_node.right = insertRecursive(root_node.right, key);
        }
    }else{
        root_node = new Node(key);
    }
    return root_node;
}
```

Your `searchRecursive` code also has a bug. Your current code says:

```
if(root_node != null) {
        System.out.println(root_node.key);
    }

    if(root_node == null || root_node.key.equals(key)) {

        return root_node;
    }
    if(key.compareTo(root_node.key) > 0) {
        return searchRecursive(root_node.left, key);
    }

    return searchRecursive(root_node.right, key);
```

here, if the `key` is greater than current node's key, you are moving `left` but instead you should move `right` and so goes with the below line. So change your method implementation to

```
Node searchRecursive(Node root_node, String key) 
{ 
    //Node someNode = new Node(key);

        /**
         * TODO
         * 
         */

     //Node someNode = new Node(key);
    if(root_node == null || root_node.key.equals(key)) {
        return root_node;
    }

    if(key.compareTo(root_node.key) > 0) {
        return searchRecursive(root_node.right, key);
    }

    return searchRecursive(root_node.left, key);   
}
```

**Full Working Demo:** https://ideone.com/3WuAXf

**Update:**

As **@Maurice Perry** mentions in the comment, you don't need to create a new node just to compare the key to be added to the current node's key.

You can completely remove this line from `insertRecursive` method

```
Node someNode = new Node(key);
```

and change

```
int comparison = someNode.getKey().compareTo(root_node.getKey());
```

to

```
int comparison = key.compareTo(root_node.getKey());
```

Comment: Not sure if that's the issue. This is what I get on the console.                               BST insertion runtime is 0.0
BST search runtime for aaaa is 6.0
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at a5.BinarySearchTree.main(BinarySearchTree.java:195)

Comment: @DaGuyWhoCodes Can you share the entire code of yours via some link, say https://ideone.com/ ?

Comment: @DaGuyWhoCodes One issue I saw is that you have to put `insertRecursive` code inside `searchRecursive` method.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Can you explain that a little bit more? do you mean I should call searchRecursive inside insertRecursive method? or do you mean I should place part of my searchRecursive code inside insertR?

Comment: Yes. I would add that there is no need to create a new node (`someNode`) just to compare keys.

Comment: @DaGuyWhoCodes Great. Can you please consider accepting it?